# How do I get my Google App Engine project re-enabled for billing?

Tags: google-app-engine

My app engine app promptappointment was suddenly turned from billing enabled to the free tier tonight, this is a live production app and I need it back up asap. I have no attempts on my credit card, no outstanding balances, and while it says my payment method needs to be updated even adding another card has had no effect. Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to visit https://console.developers.google.com/project/{{project-id}}/appengine/settings (were {{project-id}} is your project id) to re-enable billing for this.

You can also follow https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/b_j5kLAHMpQ

Does this help ?

Comment: Actually I would advice to read the forum, there is several relevant infos. Hope this help.

Comment: In my case I had to open a support account just to get the billing team to migrate it and manually fix it, turns out to be an issue on Google's side. At least they will credit me back for my Silver support account I had to open to get someone to actually respond.